# how to fix this error in navigation between viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, storyboard

The error is:

> Terminating app due to   uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -
>   [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to
>   insert nil object from objects[0]'

My code is:

```
   fzphoneverify *detail=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fzphonever"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Are detail and self view controller in the same stack?

Comment: It seems like you storyboard do not have view controller with identifier fzphonever, which leads to the crash.